# Reroute a specific domain to another server IP

Tags: nginx, debian, iptables

I have a server that gets all requests from 3 different domain names.
I would like to reroute two of the domain in another local IP.

**Actually I have :**

- abc.com => my_server
- subdomain.abc.com => my_server
- subdomain2.abc.com => my_server

**And I would like to get :**

- abc.com => my_server
- subdomain.abc.com:* => my_server => 192.168.0.70:*
- subdomain2.abc.com:* => my_server => 192.168.0.72:*

But I don't know how to do that, any idea, software/script name on debian ?

Thanks !

Comment: What is goal ? who or what will trigger inside 192.168.0.70 or 192.168.0.72 ?

Comment: The goal is to reroute all requests from a subdomain to another web server (ports 80 and 443). I can do that with port routing ::80 to 192.168.0.70, and ::81 to 192.168.0.72. But need a transparent reroute for users.

Comment: check my answer bellow, is what you ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use proxy for what you expect and multiply configuration to manage all port needed. Following config will proxy all request for:
subdomain.abc.com:80 => 192.168.0.70:80

```
server {
    listen 80; 
    server_name subdomain.abc.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.70:80;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately according to the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen) port number can't be dynamic and should be hard coded on your configuration file.